# WebDeploy with MSdeploy.exe fails to sync GAC Assembly because dll(s) locked by another process

Tags: gac, msdeploy, webdeploy, iisreset

I'm having this problem using msdeploy to sync GAC assembly to many Application Servers.

When I run this command

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:gacAssembly="'MyAssembly'" -dest:gacAssembly,computername=DESTINATIONSERVER
```

I obtain this error:

*Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: 
(28/09/2010 16.46.37) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer. 
---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentClientServerException: An error was encountered when processing 'INPS.DNA.dll'. 
---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: The error code was 0x80070020. 
---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MYASSEMBLY\1.0.0.0__a31fe99d2f98435c\MYASSEMBLY.dll' because it is being used by another process.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Win32Native.RaiseIOExceptionFromErrorCode(Win32ErrorCode errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FileStreamEx.CreateInstance(String path, FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FilePathProvider.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.Update(DeploymentObject source,DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleUpdate(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncDirPathChildren(DeploymentObject destRoot, DeploymentObject sourceRoot)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject
destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, Conten
tRootTable contentRootTable)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentWorkerR
equest workerRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.StatusThreadHandler.CheckForException()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AgentClientProvider.RemoteDestSync(DeploymentObje
ct sourceObject, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject
destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, Conten
tRootTable contentRootTable)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncTo(DeploymentProviderOptions
 providerOptions, DeploymentBaseOptions baseOptions, DeploymentSyncOptions syncO
ptions)
   at MSDeploy.MSDeploy.ExecuteWorker()
Error count: 1.*

If I execute **IISRESET** on DESTINATIONSERVER the error doesn't occur!

My question is:

It's possible to unlock DLL without perform an IISRESET command?

**I think I can avoid to restart entire Web Server.**

Can you help me'

Thanks a lot!

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the recyleApp provider to stop and start the app pool?

`msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp="Default Web Site",recycleMode="StopAppPool",computerName=remote-computer`

... do your real deployment ...

`msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp="Default Web Site",recycleMode="StartAppPool",computerName=remote-computer`